# OpenPDF (itext) not able to read existing signature

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature, openpdf

On creating a instance of PDFReader for the given PDF, openPDF (itext) is not able to read the signature name. But if using newer version of openPDF, I can see the signature name.

Also, If I open the pdf in text editor I can still see the annotation as below

```
/FT /Sig
/Type /Annot
/Subtype /Widget
/F 132
/T (Signature1)
/V 249 0 R
```

[PDF with signatures](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Gt7jPlUoPhXVmBPb6cJEKQcvJG5fqc4i?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please share the PDF in question for analysis.

Comment: added link in the question, original pdf has two signatures. Once we sign the original pdf, the appearance of existing signature is being removed.

Comment: Indeed, in the revision in which you signed the original pdf, the former AcroForm Fields `[248 0 R 254 0 R]` are replaced by `[null null 270 0 R 279 0 R 287 0 R 295 0 R]`. This may well be due to an error in your iText version. According to the document you use the fork "OpenPDF 1.0.0". Is updating to a current OpenPDF version an option for you?

Comment: Yes try using a current version [e.g. 1.3.30](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.librepdf/openpdf)

Comment: The pdf generation is not in our hand. Upon updating we can see the signatures but can't these broken references be fixed? The AcroForm Fields are read as PdfNull object, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: *"The pdf generation is not in our hand."* - I didn't mean updating the lib used for the generation of the original PDF but for signing. And "fixing" a signed PDF obviously does not work without breaking signatures.

Comment: Updating might open other issues. Thought if I could fix the pdf, even before or after signing. Is there any specific bug/issue which I can refer to? Thanks for your input.

Comment: I just checked, the current OpenPDF can read the names of the two existing signatures in "original.pdf". If you want to identify the required fix, simply find the version starting with which this works. From there one can go into the details changed in that version and find the minimal required change.

Comment: I would recommend trying to update, though. There are a number of bugfixes implemented...